# Combobox column in Devexpress ASPxGridView shows Datetime instead of Date

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I made that one column id GridView is lookup from stored procedure. Stored procedure is joining two tables and date in queston is date, not date time, but in GridView it's shown as Date + 0:00:00.

Any idea how to fix this?

(Ordinary columns dates are fine, but this lookup column is wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with DisplayFormatString: [documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsEditPropertiesBase_DisplayFormatStringtopic) and [demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/Features/DisplayFormat.aspx). And for general date and time format strings documentation look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97x6twsz.aspx).